# XSLT: how to select all nodes except first

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Simplified, my XML is

```
<some_XML>
  <field-list>
    <field linked="False">
      <content>words</content>
    </field>
    <field linked="False">
      <content>more words</content>
    </field>
      <field linked="True">
      <content>first</content>
    </field>
    <field linked="True">
      <content>second</content>
    </field>
    <field linked="True">
      <content>yet more words.</content>
    </field>
  </field-list>
</some_XML>
```

Linked fields may appear anywhere in the field-list, sometimes the first linked field is the second node, other times it's the 12th, still other times it's another.

My XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="some_XML">
    <html>
    <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//field-list" /> 
    closing words
    </p>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field-list">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="field[@linked='True']" /><br/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="field[@linked='True']">
    and <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need it to skip the first "and", so desired output is:

```
first
and second
and yet more words.

closing words
```

So far, I've learned that I can select the first node only using
`<xsl:apply-templates select="field[@linked='True'][1]" /><br/>`

but then I need to apply a different template on all subsequent matching nodes, but not on the first. How do I do that?

I think `position()` won't do because the first linked node may be in any position. Perhaps something with `following-sibling` could work, but I have a hard time understanding the syntax, that is, I can't seem to find an example close enough to what I need.

Processor is XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you explicitly select `<xsl:apply-templates select="field[@linked='True']" />` for processing, in your template `<xsl:template match="field[@linked='True']">` you can of course use e.g. `<xsl:if test="position() > 1"> and </xsl:if>` to output `and` only for the second, third and so on processed `field[@linked='True']`.

Comment: Thanks! The original XSL had `<xsl:apply-templates select="field" />`. That's how, in the process of trial and error, I came to think `position()` wouldn't work. Learning all the time...